# Using named scopes in rails 3.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have recently been taking a course in Rails. We are tasked with creating three named scopes in our 'Product' model. I have done:

```
  scope :books,  where( :category => 'books')
  scope :movies, where( :category => 'movies')
  scope :music,  where( :category => 'music')
```

When I call these as 'Product.books' or 'Product.movies' from the command line, I am expecting to see a return of all of my products that are books, or movies. All I get is an empty array []. Is the problem in the definition of the scopes (which I assume), or how I am trying to access them?

Comment: does Product.where(:category => "Music") return product objects with category music ??

Comment: If it does then I think scope :music,  where( :category => 'Music') should return the object too on executing Product.music

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is correct. But first check your database, may be you don't have data related to the `Product.books` or `Product.movies`.

Comment: That's good to know. I do have books and movies, even music for that matter. Just checked with a Product.all, and there are definitely Books and Music and Movies (pardon the poor English, a lot of 'ands' in there). I thought that might be the issue, that I used upper case Books in the db, and l/c in my scope, but it made no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is OK. I tried it by adding some books and movies.It worked fine and displayed books when i run Product.books.

So,your problem is empty database which is resulting in empty array.

Comment: So why is it that when I run 'Product.all', I get a return of all of my products, but Product.books gives an empty array? I see when I run Product.all that there are three items of category book.

Comment: Try Product.first ..It seems to me that you have category->book but in scope you are using category->books

Comment: Tried Product.first, and returned my first product. It says that the product category :"Books".

Comment: So,the problem seems to be with CASING..wat you need to do now is    scope :books,  where( :category => 'Books')

Comment: I'm sorry, but isn't that what I already have? Or am I missing something. 1 am here, and I'm getting a bit bleary eyed. Oh, sorry, I see what you mean, I mentioned on the bottom post that I changed the original code so it now reads  scope :books,  where( :category => 'Books')  and still get nothing. Really appreciate you sticking with me on this. Thanks.

Comment: There shouldn't have been much of a problem.But,as its not solved so will help u as much as i can.Would u mind putting up Product.first contents in here??

Comment: #<Product id: 7, title: "The Music From the Dachshund UN", description: "What happens when wienerdogs rule the world? The music from the dachshund UN", image_url: "/images/dachshund_un.jpg", price: #<BigDecimal:1f3d820,'0.1295E2',8<8>>, created_at "2011-11-02 03:39:34", updated_at: "2011-11-02 03:39:34", category: "Music">

Answer (score 1):

Is `Category` its own model that is related to `Product` (such as by has_many or has_one)?

If this is the case, you will need to do a `joins` with the `Category`

For example, see the following code:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :category
  scope :books, joins(:category).where('categories.name' => 'book')
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end
```

In this simple example, both `Product` and `Category` only have `name` attributes as strings (in the migrations), and `Category` also has product_id.

Comment: Category is a column on the db table with title, description, etc. It doesn't have it's own model.